# CodeIgniter specific input post print every time the string "on"

Tags: php, codeigniter, post

I have a strange problem... very very very strange and so impossible! It's a trap! I have in my form some input of type text that have as name like "name#0" but when i get it with $this->input->post(name#0) print every time (on empty input or not empty input is the same) the string "on"... WHat the hell !?

The code is this:

```
public function ColoredHTMLTable($heading, $data, $table, $num, $checkhtml) {
    $this->CI = & get_instance();
    $tab = $table . "#" . $num;

    $alias = empty($this->CI->input->post($tab)) ? $table : $this->CI->input->post($tab);

    $this->SetFont('dejavusans', '', 18, '', true);
    $html = "<b>$alias</b><br>";
    $this->writeHTML($html, true, false, false, false, '');
    $this->SetFont('dejavusans', '', 13, '', true);
    $html = "<table cellspacing=\"1\" cellpadding=\"0\" width=\"100%\"><thead><tr bgcolor=\"#F6AC00\" border=\"1px\">";
    $field = "#" . $num;
    $width_array = array();
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($heading as $fd) {
        $str = $table . "_" . $fd . "_alias" . $field;
        $width = $table . "_" . $fd . "_width" . $field;
        $perc = $this->CI->input->post($width);
        array_push($width_array, empty($perc) || $perc < 1 || $perc > 100 ? 0 : $perc);
        $alias = empty($this->CI->input->post($str)) ? $fd : $this->CI->input->post($str);
        $width = $width_array[$i] != 0 ? "width=\"" . $width_array[$i] . "%\"" : "";
        $html .= "<th height=\"40px\" style=\"vertical-align:center\" align=\"center\" $width><b>$alias</b></th>";
        $i++;
    }
    $html .= "</tr></thead><tbody>";
    $color = true;

    foreach ($data as $row) {
        $rgb = $color ? "#FFFFFF" : "#E0E0FF";
        $html .= "<tr nobr=\"true\" bgcolor=\"$rgb\" valign=\"center\">";
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($row as $fd) {
            $width = $width_array[$i] != 0 ? "width=\"" . $width_array[$i] . "%\"" : "";
            $fd = utf8_encode($fd);
            if (!$checkhtml)
                $fd = htmlentities($fd);
            $html .= "<td style=\"vertical-align:center\" align=\"center\" height=\"40px\" $width>$fd</td>";
            $i++;
        }
        $html .= "</tr>";
        $color = !$color;
    }

    $html .= "</tbody></table><br><br>";
    $this->writeHTML($html, true, false, false, false, '');
}
```

Other post is ok, print that what i want, but the first post in the code is that strange! I tried to print the string $tab and it's correct, in my form there is the input with name $tab, so i tried to print $this->CI->input->post($tab) and every time coming out the string "on"... What is it??? Please help me ! This morning this printed normally that what must print and now something is broken!

**EDIT**

I have solved, there was a conflict in the view that i didn't see because was difficult to find it, thanks anyway!

Comment: What about your view file..??

Comment: That's because of `#` character, use `-` instead

Comment: I have solved, accidentally i have give an input the same name and there was a conflict, thanks anyway for the answer!